# setImageBitmap() is not working

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have and ImageView and it is supposed to be filled with an image from Gallery with this code:

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            getIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            pickIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Pick an image.");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Now, everything's fine in this part of the code, the problem is in onActivityResult(), exactly in setImageBitmap() because imageView is not adopting the image from Gallery. This is the code from onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST || resultCode == PromoUpload.RESULT_OK){

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filepathColumm = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filepathColumm, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filepathColumm[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        imagePromo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        pictureFlag = 1;

    }
```

I Toast the `picturePath` attribute and it's displayed ok, the problem is exactly here:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
    imagePromo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is the XML of the ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_promo"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="1dp" />
```

I also tried selecting images from multiple sizes, but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But I don't know what I'm doing wrong

You are assuming that every `Uri` is from the `MediaStore` and that every entry in the `MediaStore` has a useful path. Neither is true.

What you should be doing is passing `selectedImage` to an image-loading library (Glide, Picasso, etc.), as those libraries not only know how to use the `Uri` properly, but they will do the image-loading on a background thread, rather than freezing the UI as you are doing here. You can also teach the image-loading library to scale the image to fit your `ImageView`, to save on heap space.

A more direct replacement for your code would be:

```
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));
    imagePromo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    pictureFlag = 1;
```

But, as noted, this will freeze your UI while the disk I/O and image decoding is going on.

Comment: thanks! the replacement helped. Anyway as you said, I'll try to implement Glide or Picasso into my project.

Answer (score 0):

Will help this,

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,bmOptions);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```